# Problem with icon after install again Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, icons

Some days ago I change my hard disk, so I need to re-install Android Studio. When I clone my project again some icons don't work (others are shown well). Icons are in right folder (when I have mouse hover the icon's name i can see them) and they are equal (64x64 PNG)[image].

Some previews of the icons appear, other not. So I can't start app because the icons that don't appear are null. I don't know what happened when I install again Android Studio, because app works fine before it.
I tried to add another icon but it also doesn't appear, I tried to create another project and use the same icon but don't work and I tried to invalidate cache and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should check on an android phone if you can download and play the app. If the problem is only with the emulator - it does get buggy, so the regular reinstalling the emulator/android studios, restarting your computer, trying to install a different emulator might work.

Otherwise:

The relevant line to look at is:

android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
This means that the app is going to the 'mipmap' folder inside your directory, and looking for a file named 'ic_launcher' - to display it as the App icon.

You need to make sure this file name exists in the proper folder, and is in the correct format(this guide might help )

How to find the image location folder

If this doesn't help: remember that icons can be displayed at different qualities for different devices (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi....) so sometimes if you want to make your own icon you need to make sure it fits the requirements (in the above guide)

Comment: I know this, icons are in right folder but android studio doesn't want to see ic_launcher either (in manifest the preview of ic_launcher is equal to grey preview of image above). I tried to create an apk and app crash so I think the problem are icons.

Comment: I think the problem is size or resolution in icon ? can you try small size of icon ?

Comment: I don't think, because all the icons are equal (same format, same width/height) but, as you can see from the image I inserted, one of them appear (electronic_marker) and other don't appear (sport_marker).

Answer (score 1):

"Some previews of the icons appear, other not.", From this statement of yours, means the studio cannot locate it though you can manually see theme by your eyes. This happens sometimes in the studio.

The solution is simple "Just try to reload your image files(replace them with the same files), The ones the studio can't locate".

Also you may have your app is not able to locate an image file from a 'mipmap' folder for API less than 24, you just have to navigate your studio view from Android View  to Project View and move your image file from a specified folder to default image folder. ie. from  drawable<24> to drawable folder then relocate your file in your code.